# What are projective morphisms in derived algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-algebraic-geometry

I was curious if someone could point me to a reference or tell me if there is any notion of projective morphism between derived schemes? What about a notion of Proj? Also I am interested in what blow-ups are in the derived setting.

Comment: In the spectral setting, projective space is discussed in Lurie's SAG.